# connection lost when waiting for connack response using mqtt websockets for ibm bluemix watson iot

Tags: websocket, erlang, ibm-cloud, mqtt, watson-iot

I'm able to perform ssl & websocket handshake. The http connection is getting upgraded to websocket connection which is fine. The erlang websocket client is getting connected to the IBM Bluemix server.

But after some time I receive `ssl_closed` response which closes down the connection. I was sending `ping` request to the server and was getting response for it in binary format (which might be pong (`{binary,<<10,0>>}` .. haven't decoded the binary response frame).

```
SockReply : {ok,{sslsocket,{gen_tcp,#Port<0.2284>,tls_connection,undefined}, <0.52.0>}} 
Socket : {sslsocket,{gen_tcp,#Port<0.2284>,tls_connection,undefined}, <0.52.0>} [debug] [d:6xxxxx:myFybr123:streetlight_123@172.16.1.237:57054] 
SENT: CONNECT(Q0, R0, D0, ClientId=d:6xxxxx:myXXXX123:streetlight_123, ProtoName=MQTT, ProtoVsn=3, CleanSess=true, KeepAlive=300, Username=use-token-auth, Password=**)
```

> [info] [Client <0.36.0>] connected with wss://6xxxxx.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com:443
>
> [warning] [Client <0.36.0>] Connection lost for: ssl_closed when state is waiting_for_connack
>
> Message : {ssl_closed, {sslsocket, {gen_tcp,#Port<0.3922>,tls_connection,undefined}, <0.74.0>}}

Why am I receiving `ssl_closed` after getting connected?

Comment: Check the erlang and TLS versions you are using.  I  have seen indications of different SSL behaviours for erlang versions